# sessionid missing and session_key=None

Tags: python, django, session, cookies, django-rest-framework

For my view, how come I am seeing `session_key = None` ?

```
@csrf_exempt
@api_view(['GET'])
def shuffle(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        request.session['selected'] = []
        request.session['words'] = []
        print(request.session.session_key)    # None
        response = Response(data={'dice': 2}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
    else:
        response = Response(status=status.HTTP_405_METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED)
    return response
```

I thought django would take care of generating everything sessions related as soon as I start modifying the sessions dictionary. In my settings.py I have `SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST = True` as well. Going to check the developer tools, I also don't see the `sessionid` in my cookies. I see the row get added into my `django_sessions` table. How can I modify this session if I can't retrieve it via `sessionid` in cookies as well as `request.session.session_key` in my view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run `request.session.save()` before requesting the `request.session.session_key`